# CakePHP Media Plugin - Upload Folder

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3

I am using the Media Plugin (http://www.ohloh.net/p/cakephp-media).

I wanna define custom folder for all the uplaods. i am a little confused where it has to be done.
This is the folder structure i want to achieve

```
webroot/media/image/original (for the original file storage)
webroot/media/image/large (for the large image filter)
webroot/media/image/medium (for the medium image filter)
webroot/media/image/small (for the small image filter)
```

also i want to use a random name that i want to generate using the following sript.

```
//UUID generator
function _imgName() {
    return time() . substr(md5(microtime()), 0, 12);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, having used this plugin, I would recommend considering the default directory structure to keep your app simpler. You don't want to edit the plugin directly as it will make upgrading more painful...

```
# /app/webroot/media/transfer/img/slug.ext (for the original file storage)
# /app/webroot/media/filter/l/img/slug.ext (for the large image filter)
# /app/webroot/media/filter/m/img/slug.ext (for the medium image filter)
# /app/webroot/media/filter/s/img/slug.ext (for the small image filter)
```

However, the Media plugin configuration file is located at `/app/plugins/media/config/core.php` and contains *some* constants that you can override application-wide by defining them in `/app/config/bootstrap.php` *first*. To achieve a format somewhat similar to what you want, you could define the following variables:

```
define('MEDIA_TRANSFER', WWW_ROOT . 'media' . DS . 'original' . DS);
define('MEDIA_FILTER', WWW_ROOT . 'media' . DS);
define('MEDIA_TRANSFER_URL', 'media/original/');
define('MEDIA_FILTER_URL', 'media/');

# /app/webroot/media/original/img/slug.ext (for the original file storage)
# /app/webroot/media/l/img/slug.ext (for the large image filter)
# /app/webroot/media/m/img/slug.ext (for the medium image filter)
# /app/webroot/media/s/img/slug.ext (for the small image filter)
```

(Note: you can also set the above paths on a per-model basis by passing the correct configuration options when adding the behavior to your models.)

You can also redefine the names of the image filters being used to get a step closer to your goal. You need to do this in `/app/config/bootstrap.php` again, but *after* you have loaded the Media plugin configuration:

```
require APP . 'plugins' . DS . 'media' . DS . 'config' . DS . 'core.php';
Configure::write('Media.filter.image', array(
    'small' => array('convert' => 'image/png', 'zoomCrop' => array(100, 100)),
    'medium' => array('convert' => 'image/png', 'fitCrop' => array(300, 300)),
    'large' => array('convert' => 'image/png', 'fit' => array(600, 440)),
));

# /app/webroot/media/original/img/slug.ext (for the original file storage)
# /app/webroot/media/large/img/slug.ext (for the large image filter)
# /app/webroot/media/medium/img/slug.ext (for the medium image filter)
# /app/webroot/media/small/img/slug.ext (for the small image filter)
```

If you read the documentation for the [`Media.TransferBehavior::transferTo()` method](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/blob/3a166c18034ab166653b84af0a3a661175299c12/models/behaviors/transfer.php#L312), you will see you can customize the latter part of the path (ie. `img/slug.ext`) by reimplementing this method in your model (eg. `MyModel::transferTo()`). Something like this would get you even closer:

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {
    public function transferTo($via, $from) {
        extract($from);
        $mime = Mime_Type::guessName($mimeType ? $mimeType : $file);
        $name = $this->_imgName();
        $path  = $mime . DS . $name
        $path .= !empty($extension) ? '.' . strtolower($extension) : null;
        return $path;
    }
}

# /app/webroot/media/original/image/129916996632c787226a0b.ext (for the original file storage)
# /app/webroot/media/large/image/129916998392a3570a1828.ext (for the large image filter)
# /app/webroot/media/medium/image/12991699891c7625bebedb.ext (for the medium image filter)
# /app/webroot/media/small/image/12991699938ab22d80cfc6.ext (for the small image filter)
```

While not exactly what you were looking for (`/large/image/` vs `/image/large/`), this is about as far as you can go without reimplementing larger portions of the plugin. This is because the path is treated as two parts (eg. `/media/large/` and `image/129916998392a3570a1828.ext`) that get appended together later. You can see the append operation happening in the [`Media.TransferBehavior::_prepare()` method](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/blob/3a166c18034ab166653b84af0a3a661175299c12/models/behaviors/transfer.php#L499) and in the [`Media.GeneratorBehavior::make()` method](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/blob/f9d0f1733589386b54831052826707adf33f998f/models/behaviors/generator.php#L152). You would need to either extend the plugin and duplicate those methods (with alterations) in your application code, or hack those two lines directly to get the desired output!

Comment: wow. thanks a lot Deizel for the answer. was just hoping the path could be changed with out hacking :)

Comment: am getting this error GeneratorBehavior::make - Directory `C:\wamp\www\test\app\webroot\media\large\C:\wamp\www\test\app\webroot\img\` could not be created or is not writable. Please check the permissions.  and the path is also not what i want :(